# Using the system's time zone settings in PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, timezone

So I have a web app written in PHP that will run on different Ubuntu servers around the world.
Some of the servers will be configured to run on local time, some will run on UTC, it depends on the customer.

While I can edit the php.ini-file and set date.timezone, manually enter such data is bound to get wrong one day.

How can I get PHP to use the time zone already defined in the system (tzdata)?

Or, in other words: How can I extract (the long) time zone name from the system in PHP to use in date_default_timezone_set()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have timezone set you could use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

Or http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-name-from-abbr.php

Comment: date_default_timezone_get() won't help me, since neither date.timezone in php.ini is set, and I haven't done date_default_timezone_set() yet. But timezone-name-from-abbr() was the missing link, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

With the help that Andrey Knupp gave in his answer, I was able to solve this one.

```
echo "Time: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "<br>\n";

$shortName = exec('date +%Z');
echo "Short timezone:" . $shortName . "<br>";

$longName = timezone_name_from_abbr($shortName);
echo "Long timezone:" . $longName . "<br>";

date_default_timezone_set($longName);
echo "Time: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "<br>\n";
```

Gives output:

```
Time: 2011-12-23 23:29:45
Short timezone:MYT
Long timezone:Asia/Kuala_Lumpur
Time: 2011-12-24 06:29:45
```

**Update**: The short name for the time zones are not unique. For instance, in both America and Australia there is an "EST", leading     timezone_name_from_abbr  to sometimes pick the one I don't want to... You can ask date how big the offset is, and that can be used to further match the correct time zone:

```
$offset = exec('date +%::z');
$off = explode (":", $offset);
$offsetSeconds = $off[0][0] . abs($off[0])*3600 + $off[1]*60 + $off[2];
$longName = @timezone_name_from_abbr($shortName, $offsetSeconds);
```

Comment: Thanks for your simple solution. I only needed to provide the initial guess for my users. To this appilication, it does not matter if the sytem time becomes the default. Your guess worked very well.